# Abstract innerclass in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, polymorphism

```
abstract class Model {
    abstract class View extends ModelView<this>;

    getView(){
        return new View();
    }
}

abtract class ModelView<M extends Model> {}
```

---

```
class Shape extends Model {
    View = class {
        constructor(){ console.log("view created"); }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve code like this, which I think is well-structured.

Is this possible within react, to have a class as a subclass of another -- and have it as an abstract property (preferably static).

Comment: I think you are looking for the term *inner class*, not "subclass"

Comment: Why not? It's Polymorphous

Answer (score 2):

I think i got this.

In TS syntax like this `attribute: Item { ...` means that `attribute` is instance of class `Item`. If you want `attribute` to be class Item (not a instance) you should use syntax like this `attribute: { new (...args): Item } {...`. So final code should looks like:

```js
abstract class ModelView<M extends Model> {}


abstract class Model {
    public View: { new(...args): ModelView<Model> };

    getView(): ModelView<Model> {
        return new this.View();
    }
}
```

and then in `Shape` class you can do this:

```js
class Shape extends Model {
    View = class {
        constructor(){ console.log("view created"); }
    }
}
```

And code will be type safe.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20ModelView%3CM%20extends%20Model%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Model%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20View%3A%20%7B%20new(...args)%3A%20ModelView%3CModel%3E%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getView()%3A%20ModelView%3CModel%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.View()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Shape%20extends%20Model%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20View%20%3D%20class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%20console.log(%22view%20created%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

------Edited------

If you want to View be static and readonly you have to change little bit `getView` implementation to this:

```js
public static readonly View: { new(...args): ModelView<Model> };

getView(): ModelView<Model> {
    return new Model.View();
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :) Could you approve my answer to be more visible for others?

Comment: Sure, check Edited part of answer

Comment: With View no longer being abstract, `getView` from the base `Model` class won't work polymorphically

Comment: `View` have to inherit from `ModelView<Model>` and ModelView can be abstract but you will not be able to do `View = ModelView` in `Shape` class. Also ModelView does not inherits from Model, it only requires it in generic type

Comment: Is this a solution that you're looking for?

Comment: I preferred the syntax `new () => ModelView`, also it the class should extend  `ModelView<this>` not `ModelView<Model>`

Comment: with `{ new (...args): ModelView ` syntax  you can use static attributes, with `new () => ModelView` no. Inside `Model` class `this` it equal `Model`, so it's the same.

Comment: but `this` is not equal to `Model` within extensions of model, which is the whole point of the *abstract* class

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for something like the following?

```
abstract class Model {

  // don't use "class" here; the type of a constructor has new(...) in it:
  abstract View: new () => ModelView<this>;

  getView() {
    return new this.View(); // View is an instance property, need "this"
  }
}

abstract class ModelView<M extends Model> { }

class Shape extends Model {
    View = class {
        constructor(){ console.log("view created"); }
    }
}
```

If that meets your needs, great.  If not, please edit your question to include more info about your use case.  Hope that helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: I actually prefer this answer, as it has uses the more succinct  `new () => ModelView<this>;` notation. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Don’t think you can have abstract static properties at all, no.

Comment: Would the next best thing be a abstract `getViewClass` function? So each Model must declare a View, still -- that could be static

Comment: Also, this doesn't work as expected. In the example `Shape` class, an error occurs at the declaration of View

Comment: I don't get any such error when I test it, so without more information I don't think I can help you.  I strongly suggest editing your question with all the information relevant to your issue (e.g., "`static readonly`" is not mentioned in your question).  Good luck.